# How to link from path elements in one svg to a different element of another svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to append a hyperlink to a d3 svg chart's path/area, such that, when clicked, the 'svg' path" points you to the destination an different "svg"  on the same page. `http://plnkr.co/edit/y2f9yUapCmYDI5sM6spK?p=info`

Here's some of the problematic code:

```
    state.append("text")
        .attr("x", (10))             
        .attr("y", padding.top/2)
        .attr("class", "multiples-title")  // original line
//        .attr("class", "multiples-title-" + selectedState)            // variation 2
//        .attr("xlink:id", "#" + selectedState + "headline")   
     .attr({ "xlink:href": "#" + selectedState})
//     .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
            //alert('aaa');
//            d3.select(this)

   //             .attr({ "xlink:href": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+selectedState + "2"})

//        })     
        .text(selectedState.replace(/_/g, ' '));//.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Fragment identifiers is probably what you need. https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. You want to scroll to the corresponding svg when clicked on a path in the first chart, right? Would it be fine if jQuery is used?

Comment: Sure, jQuery sounds like a solution; I'd learn a lot from seeing how it would be implemented here. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the implementation:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUGptY69TVEfZaSFs5QE?p=preview)

```
paths.on('click', function (d) {
          var state = d.state.replace(/\s+/g, '_'),
            offset = $('svg.state.'+state).offset();
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offset.top, scrollLeft: offset.left
          });
        });
```

And of course, included jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: My goodness -- this works! Thank you so much. This is the first time I've ever seen jQuery used, and actually understood how it works.

Comment: No problem! :) Yeah, I do use jQuery quite a bit, it really comes in handy when d3 seems complicated.